# Existence of coordinate charts which coordinate vectors are principal directions

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ be a compact surface in $\mathbb R^3$. Suppose  Gaussian curvature is positive $K>0$ and $q\in S$.

I would like to find a coordinate chart $\phi$ at $q$ such that coordinate vectors $\partial_u\phi,\partial_v\phi$ are principal directions of second fundamental form in $q$.

**Question:** How do I assure it's existence?

Comment: I believe that you will find the relevant material in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1166858/2002) question and the answer to it.